# Trying to port console application to MFC GUI, but have issues with stdafx

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

So the console application works fine as a console application. Now I created a MFC GUI application and the dialog itself works fine. When i add the console application files to the MFC project, it complains about how stdafx.h is missing from the console application's files. Now I know I should add `#include "stdafx.h"` to the top of the cpp files, but there's just so many of them and the program worked fine without it. There is no MFC in the console application files so I don't see why I need to include it. I tried turning off precompiled headers, but it takes longer to compile. How do I allow precompiled headers, but turn it off for selected files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring up the Properties sheet when you have a file in File View selected, you can enable or disable precompiled headers for that file.